# How to read multiple table and redirect users to different pages based on their role

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I am currently working on login page which can redirect different roles (Parent & teacher) to different pages. However, there is 3 tables in my Microsoft SQL Server database which are:

**[account]**

AID (PK) | username | password

**[account_role]**

RoleID (PK)(FK) | AID (PK)(FK)

**[role]**

RoleID (PK) | RName

I'm trying to verify different users once they clicked the login button and redirect them to different pages. And I think the problem is here:

```
string checkrole = "select RName from [account] where username= '" + TextBoxUser.Text + "'";
SqlCommand roleCom = new SqlCommand(checkrole, con);
string role = roleCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
if (role == "Teacher")
{
    Session["New"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
    Session["Username"] = TextBoxUser.Text;
    Response.Redirect("HomeTeacher.aspx");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("HomeParent.aspx");
}
```

The RName column in table [role] is not from the same table with [account], so how can I change it to make it works? Pls help

Comment: You need to join it from the table holding the field

Comment: @NitinSingh you mean I have to join table [account] & [role] ? Can u help me for that?

Answer (score 1):

You must [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) the tables

```sql
SELECT r.RName
FROM
    account a
    INNER JOIN account_role ar
        ON a.AID = ar.AID
    INNER JOIN role r
        ON ar.RoleID = r.RoleID
WHERE
    a.username = @user
```

It is also better to use command parameters

```
roleCom .Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TextBoxUser.Text);
```

Note that when using command parameters the SQL text does not contain any string delimiters. The parameter mechanism takes care of escaping embedded apostrophes, formatting dates etc. It also prevents [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

```
public string GetRole(string userName)
{
    using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        try
        {
            var query = @"select r.rname from role r
                            join account_role ar
                              on r.roleid = ar.roleid
                            join account a
                              on a.aid = ar.aid
                          where a.username = ""@userName""";
            using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand(query, dbConn))
            {
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;

                SqlDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    var result = reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            throw; // bubble up the exception and preserve the stack trace
        }

        dbConn.Close();

        return result;
    }
}
```